# get $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] without using superglobals

Tags: php, document-root

I'm running a PHP script from the command line, so superglobals are not defined. How can I get the $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] without using the superglobal $_SERVER?

Comment: `__DIR__` magic constant may come in use...

Comment: There is no `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` in the CLI version of PHP. It doesn't make any sense. In the CGI version, it contains the filesystem directory that is served as the website root directory by the web server. In the CLI version there is no web server and no web site.

Comment: In the 'bootstrap' file i always define a constant 'APP_ROOT_DIR', 'DOCUMENT_ROOT' etc. 'depending on the environment the script is run from. maybe useful?: [A PHP bootstrapping crash course](https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/php-bootstrapping-crash-course/146)

Comment: Do people still READ questions?! This gets downvoted probably 'cause people think superglobals aren't defined, so using $_SERVER is useless... THAT IS JUST WHAT I STATED! SO THAT'S WHY I'M ASKING FOR AN ALTERNATIVE... thanks @ʰᵈˑ for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Superglobals such `$_SERVER` haven't been set yet (because Apache/Nginx/etc) sets these values. As you're running from the command line, there is no Apache/Nginx/etc to set them, thus resulting in them becoming `NULL`.

There are 2 alternatives you can use.

#### Using `__DIR__`

You can use the [magic constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) `__DIR__` to output the directory of the current file.

```
php -r "echo __DIR__;"
/var/www/html
```

This will give different results depending on where you run it from. I.e: `/var/www/html/lib/foo` will return differently if you ran it from `/var/www/html/views/index`. - which is probably not what you're looking for.

#### Setting your own constant

Within your bootstrap file ([as mentioned in this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31048615/get-serverdocument-root-without-using-superglobals?noredirect=1#comment50118891_31048615)), you can set your own constant to be used throughout your application.

```
define('__DOCUMENT_ROOT__', __DIR__);
```

Now from within the page you run (as long as it uses your bootstrap file), you can call `__DOCUMENT_ROOT__` constant to get the value that *would* mirror `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]`. Though this would require you to use relative paths to include your bootstrap file.

Answer (score 0):

When you use cli, all server variables (and $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]) is meaningless. If you want to resolve script directory, you can use `__DIR__`